# Which chapters are left out during in the anime of Attack on Titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I've recently started reading the *Attack On Titan* manga. I started from chapter 35 and skipped over 1-34 because that's where the anime left off and I already watched it.

I just want to know which chapters I should go back and read without having to reread all of them (because I'm lazy and I know I'll lose interest if I do)

Comment: That what i actually did. But i did check some of the chapter from 1-34, i did not find and missing part from anime so i did not bother to read from the beginning.

Comment: There is a cut seen where annie is sad about mina's death in the battle of trost. I believe it's cut in some animes but not others. Don't no why.

Answer (score 8):

I have read from the beginning. From what I remember, the anime didn't leave much out if anything at all. It just stopped at a really bad point. The main difference is that the manga did not progress linearly and employed a lot of flashbacks.

Comment: One IMHO important side arc left out is about Ilse's Journal, though there _is_ [a separate OVA](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Ilse%27s_Notebook:_Record_of_a_Fallen_Soldier) of that.